# Can i return a value from a function and have the function keep running code

Tags: java

I am implementing an interface.

I have two functions that I have to implement A and B. A checks the file is not corrupt and return then B processes the file and returns. after B return function C runs, I have no control over C as I am just implementing A and B.

The problem is that B takes a long time to run  and C needs it return value to run. Ideally I would split B into B and D and put all the stuff that C dose not need to run into D. As this is impossible I want to know if it is possible to return a value from B so C can run but afterwards then have B run more code.

C cannot be called from B.

Comment: Sounds like a case for multithreading.

Comment: @ Kerrek If I multi threaded would I be able to guarantee that C ran before the other half of B because if they ran parallel it would be pointless. Also can I implement multi-threading if im only implementing and interface?

Comment: I don't understand your specification. You say that at the moment you run `x = B(); C(x);` and that's fine, but now you want to split up `x = B1(); C(x); B2();` and you say that `C()` *must* finish before `B2()` starts? Then how was the original setup correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`A` must call `B` and `C`  You want `B` to do some processing, `C` to be called and `B` to continue processing.

The simplest approach is to have

`A` called a method on `B` which opens the file and does some processing, and leaves anything open which is need later. `A` calls `C` and then calls another method on `B` which finishes the processing.  This means `B` must know when to stop and return so `C` can be called.

The way around this is to use a listener interface below.

```
class A {
   void method(B b, C c) {
      b.function(new Listener() {
          public void onValue(long num) { // or any event type
             if (num > 100) C.something();
          }
      });
   }
}
```

This way `B` has no idea when `C` will be called.

---

You can implement a listener interface which you pass to the function and it can "return" multiple values.  However once a function actually `return`s it is no longer running.

This function can run in another thread or the same thread.

```
interface Listener {
     public void onValue(long num);
     public void onError(Exception e);
     public void onEndOfData();
}

public void function(Listener l) {
    try {
       for(int i=0;i<10;i++) l.onValue(i);

       // read a file 
    } catch (Exception e) {
       l.onError(e);
    } finally {
       l.onEndOfData();
    }
}
```

put another way instead of doing something like

```
// only one value.
long value = function();
System.out.println("value returned was "+value);
```

you can do

```
// any number of values can be returned 
// and the function can keep processing.
function(new Listener() {
    public void onValue(long value) {
        System.out.println("value returned was "+value);
    }
});
```

Comment: i dont understand what you are talking about sorry :(

Comment: Every call to the listener is another values "returned" to the calling code. See my edit.

Comment: I think what @Peter means that your C will implement Listener interface (and hence all of its method). In C, the code which is dependent on B should be placed in onValue() method. While calling B you have to pass "this" to that function of B class. I hope I understood it correctly.

Comment: @Naved I cant affect C though. C is a function performed by the server that I have no control over that they want run as soon as possible but both my functions run before C.

Comment: @Skeith, You want it ASAP, but you can't run it first. What do you need to wait for?

Comment: @Peter its a server that calls functions. its programmed to run C after it has spoken to me. all I can do is write the functionality of A and B. C should run before B but that not how the software does it and we dont have the source code for the server, were at its mercy :(

Comment: @Skeith, So you need B to trigger some work which continues after it has returned?  In that case you need to pass this work to another thread which runs after B returns.

Answer (score 1):

You could have B schedule the long-running task to execute on another thread (eg a Timer or Executor) then return the value without having to wait for the long-running task to complete.

Comment: how would i do this ? im not to good at java could you give and example please.